# Add additional menu items to the contextual menu on right click on NSWindow tabs

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

Currently macOS supports window tabbing and we can merge multiple windows into tabs on a single window. Right now if we do a right click on the tab, it shows default menu items in contextual menu such as "Close Tabs", "Close Other Tabs", "Move Tab to New Window". However Safari tabs has one additional menu item as "Pin Tab" and Xcode tabs has additional item as "New Tab".

[image]
[image]

I would like to achieve something similar to this in my mac application. How do I add additional menu items to this contextual menu in my application. I have looked into the documentation for `NSWindow`, `NSWindowController` and `NSDocument` but none of it mentions anything about this contextual menu. It would be really helpful if someone who has implemented something similar can share some ideas about how to approach this.

Answer (score 3):

You can observe the `NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification` notification. It will fire before the menu appears. You can add you items to the menu directly, or assign a delegate and add them in the `menuNeedsUpdate:` method. Be careful not to add your items multiple times, as the notification will fire before the menu opens each time.

The target of the menu item is automatically set to the window represented by the tab. Here is a complete example:

```
@implementation TabbedWindow

BOOL didAddMenuItem;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self toggleTabBar:self];

    self.title = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(menuDidStartTracking:) name:@"NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification" object:nil];
}

- (IBAction)newWindowForTab:(id)sender
{
    TabbedWindowController* twc = [[TabbedWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"TabbedWindowController"];
    [self addTabbedWindow:twc.window ordered:NSWindowAbove];
    [twc.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}

- (void)menuDidStartTracking:(NSNotification*)sender
{
    if(didAddMenuItem)
        return;

    NSMenu *tabMenu = (NSMenu *)sender.object;

    NSMenuItem *myMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My cool item" action:@selector(myCoolAction:) keyEquivalent:@""];

    NSMenuItem *anotherItem = [tabMenu itemAtIndex:0];
    myMenuItem.target = anotherItem.target;

    [tabMenu addItem:myMenuItem];

    didAddMenuItem = YES;
}

- (void)myCoolAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"You clicked on the tab for: %@", self.title);
}
```

Note that I tried this code in a custom `NSWindow` subclass. You may also want to check which `NSMenu` is sending the notification - depending on your app, it could be a different context menu, the main menu, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is that how do I connect this menu item to particular tab so that I can know which tab user did the right click. Otherwise all tabs will respond to the notification and the menu action will be performed on all of them

Comment: Yes, good question. Can't see an obvious way. I recommend you file an enhancement request with Apple to get a decent public API on tabs... The feature seems a little "immature"

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. But I doubt they will reply anytime soon.

Comment: @adev actually, I did another quick test. The target of the added menu item is set to the window associated with the tab that was clicked on. So as long as the selector specified for the "action"  exists on the window subclass, it should be dispatched as you expect.

Comment: I had tried your answer, but it always gives callback for the current active window in tab. If I right click on another tab and then clicks on Test Menu option, it is still only getting called for current active window where as I expect it to call it on the tab which I right clicked. The issue is in finding which tab got right clicked in this case.

Comment: @adev I just tried this and it does work. I provided a complete implementation of my NSWindow subclass. When I click my custom menu item, the title of the window associated with that tab is printed.

Comment: I forgot to mention, my case I dont have NSWindow subclass but NSWindowController subclass. But still it should work same right? But I am always printing title of current active window if I do this.

Comment: As far as I can see, you need to do the work in NSWindow subclass. It's not hard to subclass NSWindow and it can reference it's controller through the .WindowController property.

Comment: Is it possible to share a sample project with above code somewhere which I can download and try out. I am having difficulty in trying this approach in my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tried your code. After initial launch, if i add more tabs and then right click one of the tabs which is not active, it still prints title of current active window. Do you have any idea why that is happening? It works fine after first try though. Anyways this answer is close to actual one except for this bug. Please let me know if you know the answer.

Comment: Definite bug but I don't know why. I fixed it by manually forcing the target of the new menu item, taking it from an existing item in the menu. That fixes the problem. The code is definitely a bit "smelly" but the API's used are all sanctioned and it seems to work just fine now. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. This works for now. I know it is not the best way to do it. But I will take this for now. I will keep the answer open for any other suggestions too. But giving you the bounty for being so patient with me and helping me out. You can update the answer in your github project too for anyone looking there.